# Read `ajax.Responder` with selenium

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, selenium

I've got a web site that I want to scrap data from. In the source code the data looks like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    ikariam.getClass(ajax.Responder, [
        ["updateBackgroundData",
        {
            "name": "Cassiopeia",
            "id": "57943",
            "phase": 4,
            "isCapital": true,
            "ownerId": "23629",
            "ownerName": "testUser0123",
            "islandId": "416",
            "islandName": "Stroerdoios",
            "islandXCoord": "37",
            "islandYCoord": "59",
            "buildingSpeedupActive": 1,
            "showPirateFortressBackground": 1,
            "showPirateFortressShip": 0,
            "underConstruction": 15,
            "endUpgradeTime": 1537358795,
            "startUpgradeTime": 1537324884,
            "speedupState": 38,
            "spiesInside": null,
        }],
        ["updateTemplateData", ""],
        ["popupData", null],
        ["ingameCounterData", null],
        ["removeIngameCounterData", null],
        ["updateBacklink", null]
    ]);
});
</script>
```

How can I get the `name` or the `isCapital` for example in my java application?

Comment: _read this data_ .... which data exactly?

Comment: The name (cassiopeia) for example

Comment: Update the question with a bit of the _outerHTML_

Comment: @New contributor updated